# DAX A Day-on-Day change to compare multiple Stocks in a Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

Here is the Sample PBIX File - [Here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/twY0rAUM#link)

Sample Data -

| StockQuoteTable | StartDate | EndDate | QuotePull.Column1.CH_SYMBOL | QuotePull.Column1.CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_OPENING_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_CLOSING_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY | QuotePull.Column1.CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL | QuotePull.Column1.CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE | QuotePull.Column1.CH_TOTAL_TRADES | QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP | QuotePull.Column1.VWAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1714.9 | 1696 | 1697 | 1709.25 | 1708.65 | 1705.25 | 12505713 | 21353650105 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 264143 | 29-Dec-23 | 1707.51 |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1721.4 | 1702 | 1709.3 | 1705.25 | 1708.85 | 1703.3 | 22038235 | 37713047859 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 423062 | 28-Dec-23 | 1711.26 |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1706.5 | 1678.6 | 1681.5 | 1703.3 | 1702.1 | 1682.45 | 13504539 | 22901880537 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 321373 | 27-Dec-23 | 1695.87 |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1685.95 | 1668.55 | 1673.25 | 1682.45 | 1684.1 | 1670.85 | 9022928 | 15144582177 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 243596 | 26-Dec-23 | 1678.46 |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1685.9 | 1667.1 | 1683.6 | 1670.85 | 1668.7 | 1686.7 | 24289425 | 40702711528 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 450284 | 22-Dec-23 | 1675.74 |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1689.75 | 1650.25 | 1657 | 1686.7 | 1685 | 1657 | 18294620 | 30604491502 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 385913 | 21-Dec-23 | 1672.87 |
| HDFCBANK | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | HDFCBANK | 1668.95 | 1644.45 | 1658 | 1657 | 1644.75 | 1652.9 | 17116260 | 28451245154 | 1757.5 | 1460.25 | 415287 | 20-Dec-23 | 1662.23 |
| IREDA | 01-Dec-23 | 31-Dec-23 | IREDA | 114.2 | 98.3 | 102 | 110.75 | 111.15 | 108.3 | 167648627 | 18085063262 | 123.2 | 50 | 527506 | 18-Dec-23 | 107.87 |
| IREDA | 01-Dec-23 | 31-Dec-23 | IREDA | 121 | 108.3 | 120.4 | 108.3 | 108.3 | 120.3 | 107529568 | 12023317404 | 123.2 | 50 | 513417 | 15-Dec-23 | 111.81 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 619.9 | 613.1 | 615 | 614.25 | 614.2 | 614.15 | 11706255 | 7210878841 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 285158 | 11-Dec-23 | 615.99 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 616.8 | 605.35 | 610 | 614.15 | 614.5 | 611.7 | 17722136 | 10822316306 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 294891 | 08-Dec-23 | 610.67 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 612.55 | 605 | 610 | 611.7 | 611.5 | 608.45 | 10725706 | 6539746290 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 248309 | 07-Dec-23 | 609.73 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 614 | 604.55 | 614 | 608.45 | 607.7 | 608.25 | 21439069 | 13076949822 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 273409 | 06-Dec-23 | 609.96 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 611.3 | 595.05 | 595.05 | 608.25 | 608.25 | 594.7 | 36430152 | 22090196336 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 432396 | 05-Dec-23 | 606.37 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 596 | 584.55 | 588 | 594.7 | 595.9 | 571.75 | 26077882 | 15393175008 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 386859 | 04-Dec-23 | 590.28 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 574.2 | 566.55 | 567 | 571.75 | 571.85 | 564.75 | 10614230 | 6069542121 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 189868 | 01-Dec-23 | 571.83 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 570.2 | 563.65 | 569.75 | 564.75 | 565.15 | 568.6 | 19758998 | 11187929537 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 314822 | 30-Nov-23 | 566.22 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 569 | 565.1 | 568 | 568.6 | 568.35 | 564.45 | 10299034 | 5845506569 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 206929 | 29-Nov-23 | 567.58 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 565.2 | 561.1 | 563.6 | 564.45 | 564.8 | 560.35 | 8153314 | 4593727820 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 186090 | 28-Nov-23 | 563.42 |
| SBIN | 01-Jan-23 | 31-Dec-23 | SBIN | 562.45 | 559.25 | 561.95 | 560.35 | 560.7 | 559.95 | 6529851 | 3660804949 | 629.55 | 499.35 | 155259 | 24-Nov-23 | 560.63 |

We can see there is a huge difference in the price of these 3 stocks, I want to compare them using the Growth % on a Day-on-Day basis.

Here is the measure I created but it isn't working -

```
'StocksList'[Growth] = VAR currDate = SELECTEDVALUE('StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP])
VAR preDate = CALCULATE(
    MAX('StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP]),
    FILTER(
        'StocksList',
        'StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] < currDate
    )
)
VAR DoDchange = DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE]),
        'StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = currDate
    ) - CALCULATE(
        MAX('StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE]),
        'StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = preDate
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE]),
        'StocksList'[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = preDate
    ),
    0
)
RETURN
    DoDchange
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong probably because all the stock data are in the same table. and I'm creating the line chart using the `QuotePull.Column1.CH_SYMBOL` column as a legend to differentiate the three.
Can anyone help me with the same?

EDIT -

What I'm looking for is a view like this as you can see we are comparing the growth/loss with the earliest value of that particular stock. -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
Growth = 
VAR date1 = CALCULATE( MIN(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP]), REMOVEFILTERS(), VALUES(StocksList[StockQuoteTable]) )
VAR date1Price = CALCULATE( SUM( StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE] ), REMOVEFILTERS(), VALUES(StocksList[StockQuoteTable]), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = date1 )

VAR change = 
DIVIDE( 
    SUM(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE]) - date1Price, 
    date1Price, 
    0
)

RETURN change
```

**EDIT**

**EDIT**

```
Growth = 
VAR currDate = MAX(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP])

VAR preDate = CALCULATE( MIN(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP]), REMOVEFILTERS(), VALUES(StocksList[StockQuoteTable]) )

VAR DoDchange = DIVIDE(CALCULATE( SUM(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE]), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = currDate ) - CALCULATE( MAX( StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE] ), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(StocksList), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = preDate )), CALCULATE( MAX( StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE] ), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(StocksList), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = preDate )), 0)

RETURN DoDchange
```

**EDIT**

Does this work?

```
Growth = 
VAR currDate = MAX(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP])

VAR preDate = CALCULATE( MAX(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(StocksList), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] < currDate ) )

VAR DoDchange = DIVIDE(CALCULATE( SUM(StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE]), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = currDate ) - CALCULATE( MAX( StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE] ), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(StocksList), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = preDate )), CALCULATE( MAX( StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE] ), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(StocksList), StocksList[QuotePull.Column1.CH_TIMESTAMP] = preDate )), 0)

RETURN DoDchange
```

Comment: No, Davide, I've edited the question this might give you a better view of what I'm trying to achieve. Let me know if you have any other clarifying questions.

Comment: So a cumulative growth/loss over time?

Comment: Yes. Cumulative P/L adds on over time granularity and it should start from 0% as a reference. Also, Can you please explain your DAX measure and how ALLSELECTED is helping in getting DoD % growth? I'm still learning. Thank you.

Comment: ALLSELECTED() removes the filter context on whatever you pass but keeps filters from any slicers. I have added a new one which gets the first date for every stock and calculates it from that point instead of previous day.

Comment: That makes sense. Your New Measure is working fine for the first stock but I think it's comparing the Initial price of the First stock to the second stock. Here is a screenshot [link](https://imgur.com/a/BLFXvWE) . It isn't picking the initial price for the second stock rather it's considering the initial price of the first stock for the second one as well, I think that is what is happening.

Comment: OK, let me clean it up and have another go.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Can you please explain how does REMOVEFILTERS() and VALUES() work here? I assume VALUES() gets the current going Stock and hence Calculate filters out only those rows?

Comment: Sure - REMOVEFILTERS() clears the entire filter context so the whole table can be seen. VALUES() simply restores the filter context for the stock in question. You can achieve the same thing with ALLEXCEPT() but this way is more flexible. As a side note, you should have a date table and clean up your column names.